# CSS Grid minmax with auto as min

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm wanting to have a grid with two columns where the leftmost column will scale based on the width of its content, but will not exceed 33% of the grid width.

However, it appears that `grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 33%) auto` does not work as intended. The leftmost column is always at 33% width even if the content is smaller.

I'm probably misunderstanding what `minmax` is supposed to accomplish. Is there some other way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 33%) auto
}

.firstcol {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.secondcol {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="firstcol">Short text</div>
  <div class="secondcol">Some more text</div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="main">
  <div class="firstcol">This text is wayyyyyy to long and it should be wrapped</div>
  <div class="secondcol">Some more text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: try  grid-template-columns: minmax(max-content, 33%) 1fr

Comment: @jpmarks doesn't make any difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about using `grid-template-columns: fit-content(33%) 1fr`

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: fit-content(33%) 1fr;
}

.firstcol {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.secondcol {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="firstcol">Short text</div>
  <div class="secondcol">Some more text</div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="main">
  <div class="firstcol">This text is wayyyyyy to long and it should be wrapped</div>
  <div class="secondcol">Some more text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated the answer. fit-content is what you are looking for. Didnt know it till now as well, thanks :)

Comment: Nice! Turns out I also had to add `word-break: break-word;` because if my text was all one word it would not be constrained to 33% but would run over.